# Shibboleth SP RequestMap not starting authn flow

Tags: shibboleth-sp

I have an application that requires different URLs to be associated to different entityID's. From my research I found that using a [RequestMap](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/SP3/pages/2065334885/RequestMap) allows me to redefine the `entityIDSelf` .

However, when give the following RequestMap in `shibboleth2.xml`:

```
<RequestMapper type="Native">
        <RequestMap applicationId="default">
            <Host name="example.com" applicationId="default">
                <Path name="path1" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" encoding="headers" entityIDself="entityId1" />
                <Path name="path2" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true" encoding="headers" entityIDself="entityId2" />
            </Host>
        </RequestMap>
    </RequestMapper>
```

and apache config:

```
<Location /Shibboleth.sso>
    UseCanonicalName On
    Require all granted
    SetHandler shib
</Location>
```

When I navigate to the either of the paths, shibboleth sp does not start the authentication flow.

Any help would be appreciated!